# Check the status of promises and based on that remove the item from list

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have a list of selected items and need to remove those items from the server. So once I get the conformation from user, I'm sending series of remove request to the server and waiting for them all to complete. And once it completes, I'm reassigned the `$scope.selected` with empty arrray.

But what I need is based on each remove request stats, I want to remove the itemfrom the `$scope.selected`.

i,e

If the first request status is 200, Remove `234` from the list and

If the second request status is 403, Do not remove it from list.

If any other request status received, I have to call an function `ReportError()`

What is the best way to do this ?

```
 $scope.selected = [234, 455, 667];

 $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
      var promises = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.selected, function(id, index){
           var promise = $itemResource.item.remove({id: id}).$promise;
           promises.push(promise);
      });

      $q.all(promises).then(onComplete);
});

function onComplete() {
    $scope.selected = [];
    $scope.getItems();
    $mdDialog.hide();
}

// $itemResouce 
angular.module('app').factory('$itemResource', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
   return {
       item: $resource('/manage/items')
   };
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onComplete` callback is passed the response of each promise as an array, so you could use those to check the status?

Also, AFAIK, a status 403 will reject the promise, no? So, your onComplete will need to be set to both the `success` and `error` callbacks.

Something like this:

```
$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
    ...
    $q.all(promises).then(onComplete, onComplete);
});

function onComplete(promises) {
    angular.forEach(promises, ...); // Check status, alter selected-array
    $scope.getItems();
    $mdDialog.hide();
}
```

Comment: Instead of pushing the promises to an array, you could use an array with the id of the request as the key, like so:
`var promises = {};`
`promises[id] = promise`

Then, you'll get that same map in the callback

Answer (score 0):

The q library has a allSettled method which is not implemented in Angular. You can add [angular-promise-extras](https://github.com/ohjames/angular-promise-extras) however, this gives your resolves and rejects. You could also write a for loop and pass an increment value to determine which one has been resolved or rejected.